# Better word for the "source" of a remix?

Tags: synonyms

For "remix" in the general sense, e.g. "everything is a remix".

Is there a better word than "source" for describing the thing that got remixed? ("Source" is just ambiguous in many contexts.)

Thanks!

Edit: "original" also has the connotation of the most upstream. If C is a remix of B, which was a remix of A, what would you call B w.r.t. C?

Comment: The original...?

Comment: Or the [*master*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/master+copy).

Comment: Added an explanation against "original". I feel "master" is similar.

Comment: I'd just use *"B is the **input** to C"* to describe that specific relationship between the two stages. In the more general context of the entire series, C is the *final* (or *current*), B is an *intermediate* remix (or *version*), and A is the *original [source]*.

Comment: Concurrence with saying _intermediate_ remix, although "input" is a bit technical for my taste in this context.

Comment: I might call B the SUBJECT of C.

Answer (score 6):

You remix the **original**. The original version of a song, for example. The original version of a film. In discussing remixes of art, audio and visual art, this is what I'd use.

Comment: In terms of music you will commonly see songs titled "Song Name (Original Mix)" vs. "Song Name (Dubstep Remix)".

Comment: I updated my q with a description against "original": I feel it has the connotation of most upstream, when the source of a remix may not be the most upstream. Thanks though!

Answer (score 3):

For audio, you remix from the *master* (or *master copy*). Generally, this will have different tracks for each instrument and singer. If you improve the *master*, for example, you remove noise from it digitally, this is called *remastering*.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I feel this suffers a similar problem as "original" though — it gives the connotation of the most upstream only, when my remix source may not be the most upstream.

Comment: Then "original" is probably the better word for your purpose.